# Hadoop doesn't use one node for job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I've got a four node YARN cluster set up und running. I recently had to format the namenode due to a smaller problem.

Later I ran Hadoop's PI example to verify every node was still taking part in the calculation, which they all did. However when I start my own job now one of the nodes is not being used at all.

I figured this might be because this node doesn't have any data to work on. So I tried to balance the cluster using the balancer. This doesn't work and the balancer tells me the cluster is balanced.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your HDFS replication factor? and why do you think that all nodes in your cluster must be used for job?

Comment: Replication factor is 3; because that would speed up the very CPU heavy computation?

Comment: So how can 4th node have data block of your input(to run a task) if cluster size is 4 and replication factor is 3?

Comment: Because HDFS doesn't need to put all replications on the same node combinations or am I mistaken here? I image file1 on nodes A,B,C; file 2 on nodes B,C,D... And then every node would have something to work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While processing, your ApplicationMaster would negoriate with the NodeManager for containers and NodeManager in turn would try to obtain the nearest datanode resource. Since your replication factor is 3, HDFS would try to place 1 whole copy on a single datanode and distribute the rest across all the datanodes.

1) Change the replication factor to 1 (Since you are only trying to benchmark, reducing replication should not be a big issue).

2) Make sure your client(machine from where you would give your -copyFromLocal command) does not have a datanode running on it. If not, HDFS will tend to place most of the data in this node since it would have reduced latency.

3) Control the file distribution using `dfs.blocksize` property.

4) Check the status of your datanodes using `hdfs dfsadmin -report`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your node is joinig the resourcemanager. Look into nodemanager log on t the problem node, see if there are errors. Look into the resourcemanager Web UI (:8088 by default) make sure the node is listed there.
2. Make sure the node is bringing enough resources to the pool to be able to run a job. Check [`yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) and [`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) in yarn-site.xml on the node. The memory should be more than the minimum memory requested by a container (see [`yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)).

Comment: 1. Yes the node joined the cluster and is listed in the rm web ui. 2. The node is equipped with 6 cores and 12gb RAM which should be more than enough; especially because it had worked perfectly fine before the cluster reset

Comment: Make sure the node uses the RAM available. Config may overwrite it. Also, make sure the node is part of the HDFS cluster too, datanode is up, runnig and connected (listed by namenode). If is not in the namenode list, it shouldn't prevent it from running jobs but is less likely to be picked up.